# jasmine: how to load my html and then run the Specrunner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jasmine

I am learning to use Jasmine with Javascript & HTML. I have created my HTML page which has an input box, few display areas and buttons. I have also written my JS code, which basically works on the DOM by adding event handlers to my input box and button. Now while trying to test my code with Jasmine, I am running SpecRunner.html with my spec file (which has few test cases on the input box) and my src file which is the same JS file I had coded earlier. But as the my input elements are not available the JS file is throwing exceptions. I tried using setFixtures() in beforeEach function of Jasmine, but I guess the JS code is getting executed before any DOM structure is getting created by setFixtures() method.

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've included [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) in your SpecRunner – `setFixtures` is not a native Jasmine call. Also make sure that you are giving `setFixtures` your html code directly, not an html file for it to open (that's what `loadFixtures` is for). I would also check your Javascript console to see if it provides any indication of what's going wrong.

Comment: Let me explain my problem statement better.

Comment: The JS code I want to test, starts with adding event handlers to the TEXT BOX in my HTML page. All the test cases I am writing are on the Input box. So now when I run the Specrunner.html which has my Spec JS and the JS code, the JS code is throwing reference error that it is unable to find the input element. Even if I add the input element using setFixtures, my JS code runs 1st and then the specJs, which still gives me the same exception. And if I include the specJS before the JS code file, the fixtures are no more available. So again same problem.